# Athena query does not return any results newer than table creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-athena

Following [the formal instructions for querying CloudFront access logs using Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html), I created a table in Athena called `default.cloudfront_logs` that points to my path in S3 where my CloudFront distribution's access logs are being written:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `cloudfront_logs`( <fields here> )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='^(?!#)([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)\\s+([^ \\t]+)$') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mybucket/examplecom'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1520796451')
```

I then verified that a query returns data:

```
SELECT date, count(*)
FROM cloudfront_logs
order by date
group by date;
```

However, in the days following the table creation no newer data is appearing in my query despite more access log files appearing in my S3 buckets (for subsequent dates).

I have tried dropping and recreating the table, however the query still returns the same results (without newer access logs data after the original Athena table creation).

Why does newer data that has appeared in S3 not show up in my Athena query results?

Comment: Just for reference: [Querying Amazon CloudFront Logs with Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html)

Comment: Is it due to your inclusion of `transient_lastDdlTime`? I'm not sure what that does, but online references suggest it is related to data updates.

Comment: It turns out that the CloudFront access log format changed Jan. 10th 2018, so my regex silently failed when parsing log files with 2 addtl columns.
I'm sad that (a) the query doesn't fail in some way, and (b) the log format change wasn't announced more publicly--I can't find a public announcement of the change.
The docs have been updated to reflect the new schema, so dropping my table created prior to Jan 10th and using the CREATE TABLE statement here resolved the issue for me: docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html 
Thank you for being communicative with me though!

Comment: Oh, good discovery! I *thought* the format looked too clean now! Do you have a reference to something that says when the format changed?

Comment: I could find no public announcement anywhere--I managed to communicate with a Glue/Athena employee through backchannels who made me aware of the log format change.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is partitioned into sub-directories, then Athena might not be aware of the newly created directories.

Use the [MSCK REPAIR TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html) to scan the partitions:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE cloudfront_logs;
```

Then, run your query again.

This will be necessary whenever the folder structure has changed.

Comment: I'm almost positive that this is not a case of my data being partitioned. All of my access log files live at the same level of S3--no sub-"folders", and reviewing my Athena `CREATE TABLE` I did not include any partition clause/instructions. I've added my `CREATE TABLE` DDL to the question details in the hope that helps clarify the situation